# What model to use when examining subject specific control variables on the outcome?

Tags: hidden-markov-model, competing-risks

I want to study whether a trader will buy or sell a stock from a given set of stocks =[1,2,3,...,n], based on the sentiment scores of these stocks [sent_1, sent_2, sent_3, ..., sent_n]. So basically I want to examine whether a high positive sentiment score for stock 2 (i.e. sent_2) leads to a buy decision for stock 2. I am not sure how to go about this problem and any help would be appreciated. My data is comprised of the buy and sell decisions of many traders for these stocks over a period of time. Moreover, I have sentiment score data for each of these stocks over the same period of time.

I am thinking along the lines of hidden Markov models but I am not sure whether this is right.

Comment: Would you be able to specify the range of values that sentiments scores can take and buy and sell decisions?

Comment: Sentiment scores are between -1 and 1, where a negative number signifies a negative sentiment and a positive number signifies a positive sentiment. As for the trading decision I have the price of the stock that is being bought or sold and the timestamp. It is possible to simply take the trade decision as a binary or categorical outcome: buy, sell, hold (if previously bought).